# Angular Expression not evaluating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very new to Angularjs. I have managed to install eclipse plugin for Angularjs and started a simple code. When i have the below code, the expressions are evaluating properly. I have visited similar problems reported in stackoverflow ad have tried all suggestions, but in my case, i just evaluate {{ 7 + 8}} which is straight forward. Please any help here is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<html ng-app>
```

As soon as i change to poing ng-app to my module, the page breaks and expressions are not evaluating.

```
<html ng-app = "corpo">    --> Fails
```

myapp.html

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="corp/WebContent/corp.js"></script>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<title>Corp</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>{{ 7 + 19 }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

corp.js

```
var corp = angular.module('corpo', []);
```

Also i keep getting undefined javascript file and i have disabled the validation under properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put corpo below of angular library

Like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="corp/WebContent/corp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried this and no luck. :(

Comment: Sure.. `<html ng-app = "corpo">
<head>

<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="corp/WebContent/corp.js"></script>
<title>Corp</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <p>{{ 7 + 19 + 1 }}</p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: nope, this is what i see in the console. `Tern response# with 38ms: 
{}
{"query":{"type":"angular","subtype":"type","angularTypes":["module"],"expression":"corpo","scope":{},"files":["WebContent/corp.js","WebContent/angular.js"],"file":"WebContent/corp.html"}}
Tern request#angular_type: 
Tern response#angular_type with 22ms:

Comment: did your `corp.js` in right path ? `corp/WebContent/corp.js`

Comment: wow thanks, i did change from `src="corpWebContent\corp.js"` to `src="corp.js"` and that fixed it... Awesome, i initially had this written correctly, but eclipse was complaining about undefined javascript error and had changed this but forgot to revert.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var corp = angular.module('corpo', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="corpo">
<head>
<title>Corp</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>{{ 7 + 19 }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

change this

```
<src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">        </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="corp/WebContent/corp.js"></script>
```

Comment: oops, that was a typo when i posted the question. :( and i corrected it now in the question.

Comment: @Freaky1 I update my answer. you must put crop.js after angular.js

Comment: @Freaky1 Please see this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Its failing because you have injected corp.js before angular.min.js
corp.js after angular.min.js, it will start working
```

Comment: hmm, changed it and cleared the cache, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think your `"corp.js"` is not in the right path.

[working plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6STvA76kMlIlzqn36Diy?p=preview)

Post your application directory structure. I am sure the problem is with that.